# Apache redirect subdomain to a specific folder

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, redirect, subdomain

I need to redirect all the traffic from

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/
```

to

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/folder/
```

With 'folder' being a specific folder, of course. I've tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://subdomain.domain.com/folder/ [L]
```

But it doesn't work. What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/$ http://subdomain.domain.com/folder/ [R,L]
```

The only change I made was to add `R` in the options after the RewriteRule.  That option tells Apache to do a 302 redirect.  You can use `R=301` if you want a permanent redirect.

Comment: The URL is redirected, but it gives the following error: "Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)" in Chrome under Mac OS X. The page is blank, apart from that error :(

Comment: I have edited my answer.  The first part of the RewriteRule is now `^/$` so that it doesn't end up in a redirect loop.  I'm surprised I didn't notice that when I first answered.

Comment: That did it. Would you be so kind to explain me why it was wrong with the past version? Thanks!

Comment: A RewriteRule is made up of three parts separated by spaces: the pattern, the substitute and the options.  The pattern is a regex that is matched against the request URI.  In the first version, the pattern was `^.*$` which as a regex matches any URI.  Any URI you requested would always redirect to /folder/, even if you requested /folder/, it would still send a redirect response pointing to /folder/.  In the second version, it now only matches exactly `/`.  [The Apache rewrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/) is highly recommended.

Comment: Fantastic explanation, I'll read the rewrite guide, thanks for the comment (I've written this while singing your name :) )